# How to hide all element on html page except one div using css?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to hide all on an html expect for one `<div>`, as part of a bigger problem.
I have tried...

```
body * {
  display: none;
}
#someTable, #someTable * {
  display: block !important;
}
```

But It doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have content in your body that *isn't in a tag*? Like `<body>text <div>text in div</div></body>`. Because other than that your CSS should work.

Comment: This is happening because priority order of universal selector is higher than any other selector. so when you hide elements using * selector they would not get shown by any other css selectors.

Comment: It is a drupal page. It can be very messy... I will check!

Comment: The best thing you could do, is wrap the content you want to hide and show in separate divs with their own hide/show classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pseudo-class ':not()'

```
<style>
   body *:not(.myDiv) {
        display: none;
    }
</style>


<div>1</div>
<div class="myDiv">2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: Truth is i had to be very precise on what to display:none, but this is drupal fault. In a normal situation this is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Are you sure this method works? I tested it and it doesn't

Comment: Yes (see https://jsfiddle.net/alexqoliveira/1u9tnbxz/). Well, It depends on the browser you are using (http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot())

Comment: This only works for direct children of body. Nested elements will keep invisible.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to hide all elements using `body * {display: none;}` and show the element you want called `#show` and all it's children. `#show, #show * {display: block;}`. since at this point the `#show` parent node is still hidden by the universal selector, we have to find all parents and show them too! So:

```
var parentArray = $('#show').parents();
for (var i = 0; i < parentArray.length; i++) {
    $(parentArray[i]).css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, i must use css, in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to hide all the first-level elements, and then re-display the parent container that you want:

```
@media print {
    body > * {
        display: none;
    }

    .parent {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set body visibility to hidden also set #someTable element visibility to visible.

```css
body {
  visibility: hidden;  
}

#someTable {
  visibility: visible;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>To Be HIdden
  <div id="someTable">To Be Shown</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not going to work because the body is hidden and all it's children no matter hidden or visible won't be shown.

Comment: @FarzadYZ My answer only works when body(parent element) 'display' property set to 'block' value. could you set it to block or not?

Comment: visibility is not enough. I need this to select a part of the html document to print it. Visibility hides but not remove, so when i print i get a document containing what i have to print AND 13 blank pages :D